# When recording in Excel 2016 there are lines in red with just a "." on the left of the equal sign

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, vbe

When I record macros the code does not work and there are several lines highlighted in red which have just a "." on the left side of the equal sign.

It appears to me that the macro is doing something along the lines of just registering my changes and not assigning the default settings by itself.

[image]

I got over the issue by downgrading to Excel 13 from Excel 16.

Comment: Very strange. There should be property names after the '.' ... Have you tried recording the macro?

Comment: Yes, I have tried recording the macro. It throws a syntax error when I run the macro which is expected. It is very strange the tutorials I am following don't seem to have this issue.

Comment: I've not seen that before. It's certainly not normal behaviour. Let's see if anyone else has any input before I suggest reinstalling office!!

Comment: The only foreignkeycolumn I know of is a property of ModelRelationship. What are you trying to do?

Comment: That is not valid code. what procedure are you trying to have the macro recorder accomplish?  (i.e. steps necessary to reproduce what you have done)

Comment: I am just doing random stuff like changing size of a font, filling a box. Just to try out recording some macros via the record key, but it must be the setting of my excel or something it doesn't record the macro effectively and the recorded looks like the one above. I am very new to VBA this is the first thing I tried to do. Just to record macros and read the code.

Comment: I got over the issue by downgrading to excel 13 it would be good if someone could figure out what the issue I was having with excel 16 was because no one could help me.